# Creating web service by existing WSDL schema

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, soap

Unfortunately, I am new to web services. I have a WSDL schema, which I have to provide as a service. So how can I do this?

Can someone please tell me instructions step by step?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you would want to create a web service based on an existing WSDL schema (i'm assuming you mean WSDL and not WDSL).

You could use the WSDL.exe tool that ships with the SDK to reverse engineer the WSDL file to ASMX web services (older )

You can find more details [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/ReverseEng.aspx)

However it is advised to use WCF for newer projects, you can then use svcutil.exe to reverse engineer your WSDL file instead.
find a description in a question answered [How to use a WSDL file to create a WCF service (not make a call)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950150/how-to-use-a-wsdl-file-to-create-a-wcf-service-not-make-a-call)

Hope this helps

Comment: Please do not use WSDL.EXE. Use svcutil.exe. WSDL is part of the legacy "ASMX" web service technology and should not be used for new development.

Comment: Creating WSDL first is common in large integration projects or when integration is done between different teams and platforms. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504271/asp-net-web-services-design-methodologies-top-down-and-bottom-up-whats-the-di/3504346#3504346

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka ... good to know that ... Thanks for pointing out that.